# expected expression before '!=' token... Where I'm wrong?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

```
enum LIVELLI_EMERGENZA {
    LIV_EME_UNO                                 = 0x0001,
    LIV_EME_DUE                                 = 0x0002,
    LIV_EME_TRE                                 = 0x0003
};

typedef struct Emergenza {
    int Tipo;
    short Livello;
} Emergenza;

void TrovaEmergenze()
{
    if(INPUT_GET(IN_FUNGO_EMERGENZA)) {
        Emergenza.Tipo |= EME_FUNGO_PREMUTO;
        Emergenza.Livello |= LIV_EME_UNO;
    }
    if((INPUT_GET(IN_FC_CARTER_LAMA))){
        Emergenza.Tipo |= EME_CARTER_LAMA_APERTO;
        Emergenza.Livello |= LIV_EME_DUE;
    }
}

char EmeLivello1()
{
    if((Emergenza.Livello & LIV_EME_UNO) != 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Having evaluated the mask `emergenza.livello` I'm going to check it with `& LIV_EME_UNO`. If it is different from `0`, this means that the bits in the mask is high; but I get the error "expected expression before '!=' token".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, `Emergenza` is *essentially* a datatype, not a variable. You need to have a variable of that type to use the member access operator `.`

To make `Emergenza` a variable instead of a datatype do this:

```
struct Emergenza {
        int Tipo;
        short Livello;
} Emergenza;
```

In summary, remove the `typedef`.

Comment: Then i can check [LIV_EME_UNO] only with a variable and not with a field of a struct? thanks @sourav

Comment: @F.Guerinoni What do you mean? You need to have a `struct` variable to apply the `.` operator, isn't it?

Comment: I use `Emergenza.Livello |= LIV_EME_UNO` and it's work but `(Emergenza.Livello |= LIV_EME_UNO) != 0` not work...

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The syntax used for the typedef also declares a variable named Emergenza.

Comment: @DavidCullen thanks, how can i declaration my `struct`?

Comment: @DavidCullen: Nope. Look at it again, Emergenza is the new type defined by typedef. Not a variable.

Comment: Many thanks, i solved my problem @DavidCullen @SouravGhosh
`typedef struct Emergenza{
    int Tipo;
    short Livello;
} Emergenza;

Emergenza Emer;`

and I use `Emer.livello`

Comment: @SouravGhosh: That is what I get for commenting before compiling the code. I got my struct declarations backwards... :(